# port linux created vm to windows

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine

I have a problem using an, in linux created virtual machine in windows using virtualbox.

In windows I can start the virtual machine by using the created qcow2 file, but at the grub bootloader it just shows a black screen with a white underscore at the top left corner.

The vm was created with qemu in fedora20.
I installed the newest ubuntu server (64bit) on it.
What I want to do now is, to make it available for others, especially for windows users.
I tried it with virtualbox in a windows 8.1. It shows the behavior mentioned above.

I think there are some kinds of driver issues?

If more information is needed, please let me know.

Michael

Comment: VM form, .vdi/.vmdk/.ova? Exported or copied?

Comment: .qcow2, because VB is able to import that format.
And I just copied the file.

Comment: Virtualbox uses a lot of uuids internally to identify the components, esp. disk files. You imported the qcow2 I suppose?

Comment: yes, I imported the qcow2

Answer (score 0):

I can only find that virtualbox imports .ova format files. You can use .vmdk files without conversion, but .qcow2 is not supported directly.

With the command line tool vboxmanage you have more conversion options for hard disks.

Looks like the best way is:

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 <qcow2_VM_filename> -O vdi <RAW_file_VM_filename>
```